# Implementation of text classification in MATLAB with naive bayes

Tags: matlab, classification, text-classification

I want to implement text classification with Naive Bayes algorithm in MATLAB. 
I have for now 3 matrices:

1. Class priors (8*2 cell - 8 class names, for each class its % from the training)
2. Training Data: word count matrices - (15000*9 cell- for each class, counting of every feature (word) . the last column is each word count for all the documents.
3. Test Data: a matrices with (2000*1) cell - and for each cell a list of words which represent the document.

What should I do now? I want to calculate recall and precision for the test set. I took a look in the matlab naive bayes functions, and it suppose to be simple , but I'm not sure how and where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of Naive Bayes classification,

```
x1 = 5 * rand(100,1);
y1 = 5 * rand(100,1);
data1 = [x1,y1];
x2 = -5 * rand(100,1);
y2 =  5 * rand(100,1);
data2 = [x2,y2];
x3 = -5 * rand(100,1);
y3 = -5 * rand(100,1);
data3 = [x3,y3];
traindata = [data1(1:50,:);data2(1:50,:);data3(1:50,:)];
testdata = [data1(51:100,:);data2(51:100,:);data3(51:100,:)];
label = [repmat('x+y+',50,1);repmat('x-y+',50,1);repmat('x-y-',50,1)];
```

That was my data, three classes. Now the classification,

```
nb = NaiveBayes.fit(traindata, label);
ClassifierOut = predict(nb,testdata);
```

I think you should change your data to matrix instead of cell, but the labels are okey.

Here are the results, `blue` is the training data and the rest is the classifier output for three classes.

[image]

You can also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-confus) for calculation of recall and precision for multi-class data.